# HTTP request/response with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am implementing a small web application. Every 1 second, user input should be processed, and the result (response value) displayed on the page.

The code for the architecture is as below, but how do I implement the timer which will invoke the request?

The display of result should not cause page is refresh - otherwise, the value in the textbox will be lost.

**Follow-up [DUPLICATE] 
The question is asking not only about processing request based on elapsed timer, but the end-to-end effect of displaying response back after taking in some "submit data" -- which is missing in the duplicated-question link, and is the bases of the question being asked.

**JSP** (Default.jsp)

```
 <html>
      <head></head>
        <body>        
          <br /> Input: <input type="text" id="input" />
          <div id="theResponse"></div>
      </body>
 </html>
```

**JavaScript** (MyScript.js)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input').blur(function(event) {
            var name = $('#input').val();
            $.get('MyServlet', {
                input: inputData
            }, function(responseText) {
                $('#theResponse').text(responseText);
            });
        });
    });
```

**Servlet** (MyServlet.java)

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet 
{       
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

            String input= request.getParameter("input");
            if (input.equals("")) {
                    input= "cannot be empty";
            } else {
                    //do some work ... 

                    input= "ACK";
            }
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().write(input);
    }
}
```

**Web Config** (web.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Landing page</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Its useful if you called out a reason for down-voting both Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but for that you just need to add `setInterval` to Your js code like below :

```
myFunction(){
        $.get('MyServlet', {
                input: inputData
            }, function(responseText) {
                $('#theResponse').text(responseText);
            });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input').blur(function(event) {
            var name = $('#input').val();
            setInterval(myFunction,time You want );
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input').blur(function(event) {
                var name = $('#input').val();
                setInterval($.get('MyServlet', {
                        input : name
                }, function(responseText) {
                        $('#ajaxResponse').text(responseText);}), TIME_YOU_WANT);
        });
});`